# Returning an array to a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, cs50

```
// Implements a list of numbers using a linked list

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *makelist(int argc, char *argv[]);
int check_spaces(char *input);
int *nodes(char *input, int amount);
node *add(char *input, node *list, int *numbers, int amount);


/*int delete();
int find();*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Get linked list
    node *list = makelist(argc, argv);
    //Print linked list
    for (node *ptr = list; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        printf("%i ", ptr->number);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Free memory
    node *ptr = list;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        node *next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
    char c;
    //Give choices
    printf("Do you want to (d)delete a node, (a)add a node, or (f)find a node? ");
    //Repeat if incorrect input
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == 'd' || c == 'a' || c == 'f')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong input, try again. ");

        }
    }
    while (c != 'd' || c != 'a' || c != 'f');

    //If user chose to "add" node(s)
    if (c == 'a')
    {
        char *name = get_string("");
        char *input = get_string("What are the node(s) that you want to add? ");
        int amount = check_spaces(input);
        int *numbers = malloc(amount * 4);
        *numbers = *nodes(input, amount);
        list = add(input, list, numbers, amount);
        for (node *ptr2 = list; ptr2 != NULL; ptr2 = ptr2->next)
        {
            printf("%i ", ptr2->number);
        }
        free(numbers);
        free(list);
    }
    //If user chose to "delete" node(s)
    else if (c == 'd')
    {
        printf("d");
    }
    //If user chose to "find" node(s)
    else
    {
        printf("c");
    }
    return 0;
}
//Make linked list
node *makelist(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Memory for numbers
    node *list = NULL;

    // For each command-line argument
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        // Convert argument to int
        int number = atoi(argv[i]);

        // Allocate node for number
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        n->number = number;
        n->next = NULL;

        // If list is empty
        if (list == NULL)
        {
            // This node is the whole list
            list = n;
        }

        // If list has numbers already
        else
        {
            // Iterate over nodes in list
            for (node *ptr = list; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
            {
                // If at end of list
                if (ptr->next == NULL)
                {
                    // Append node
                    ptr->next = n;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
//Add function
node *add(char *input, node *list, int *numbers, int amount)
{
    int a = 0;
    while (numbers[a] != '\0')
    {
        a++;
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        n->number = numbers[amount-a];
        // Prepend node to list
        n->next = list;
        list = n;
    }
    return list;
}
//Get command line arguments from printf
int *nodes(char *input, int amount)
{
    int *y = malloc(amount * 4);
    char *x = &input[0];
    y[0] = atoi(x);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    while (input[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            x = &input[i+1];
            y[j] = atoi(x);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return y;
}
//How many nodes are we messing with
int check_spaces(char *input)
{
    int numbers = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (input[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            numbers++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return numbers;
}

/*int delete()
{

}
int find()
{

}*/
```

The issue is stemming from C's inability to return arrays. The question is about the adding function, because the other functions are incomplete.

My whole plan was to use `atoi` to convert the users command line arguments into numbers, and then to reverse add them into the linked list. If my list was 3, 4, 5, and I put in 1,2, it would become 1,2,3,4,5 (in theory).

My nodes function is what does all the converting, and I can't return an array because of the rules of C. So I've returned a pointer instead. I thought all of the numbers were back to back because of malloc, so I had a loop going through n->number = numbers[amount - a]. The first value was spot on, but then the rest were just a bunch of garbage values.

I'm pretty sure its because the pointer only points to the first object, and the rest are in the order they were added in. I've tried messing around with accessing the other values, but with no such luck. To be honest, I feel like there's something huge I'm missing.

There has to be something I'm overcomplicating here.

Comment: Please try to limit the question to the specific function you are having problems with.

Comment: Also... try writing an actual well-defined question because I see no question in the body of your post.

Comment: Don't assume the size of `int` is 4. Could be less. Could be more. Use `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Harr Why not do memory management like everyone else do it?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `*numbers = *nodes(input, amount);`. Your description suggests that you return a points to an array, but you only keep the first value of that array.

Comment: ^^ that's leaking the memory you had just allocated in the line above it.

Comment: @trincot, Re "*That's leaking the memory you had just allocated in the line above it*", No, it's assigns to `*numbers`, not `numbers`.

Comment: Missed that, and that is a second mistake in the same place. A data type mixup. Storing a pointer in a place where an int is expected. No wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: Any reason why you read characters individually from input to form integers when there is `scanf("%d", &num);`?

Comment: I'd suggest to first make it work for adding *one* number. No counting of spaces, no array, just read an int, and prepend it to the list. Once you have that working, start extending bit by bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are, as you said, overcomplicating things.

> The issue is stemming from C's inability to return arrays

Well, the issue in itself is not clear to me.

- this `C` inability does not exist
- why do you want to return an array in a program tha creates a linked list? Why can not you do this?

> My whole plan was to use atoi to convert the users command line arguments into numbers, and then to reverse add them into the linked list. If my list was 3, 4, 5, and I put in 1,2, it would become 1,2,3,4,5 (in theory).

It just means that you want to add the elements always at the start of the list. It is not a common choice: in general is preferred to have the elements inserted at the end, preserving the order of insertion. Such a list is called *stable*.

Another common option is to insert the elements in order but preserving the order of insertion of possible duplicates. So if you add 1 1 2 3 4 the second 1 will de inserted after the first 1

> My nodes function is what does all the converting, and I can't return an array because of the rules of C. So I've returned a pointer instead

This is the `node` function

```
// Get command line arguments from printf
int* nodes(char* input, int amount)
{
    int*  y = malloc(amount * 4);
    char* x = &input[0];
    y[0]    = atoi(x);
    int i   = 0;
    int j   = 1;
    while (input[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            x    = &input[i + 1];
            y[j] = atoi(x);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return y;
}
```

What are you trying to do? You said that `atoi` would be used to convert the arguments, but now `node` "does all the converting". How can it be?

> I thought all of the numbers were back to back because of malloc, so I had a loop going through n->number = numbers[amount - a]. The first value was spot on, but then the rest were just a bunch of garbage values.

I do not understand what you are trying to say. `malloc` just allocates memory based on a single argument, the size in bytes.

> I'm pretty sure its because the pointer only points to the first object, and the rest are in the order they were added in.

Well, it is expected: pointers point to something. Only to one something. About the rest I do not see what it is. May be the other elements? Or the other nodes?

> I feel like there's something huge I'm missing.

I also believe you are. See the example and discussion below. Maybe it adds something

### restarting things: a `C` complete EXAMPLE

I will try to show you an approach that can be used for every program, but using the linked list the way you are trying to build.

Because it is a very very common assignment to students, I will leave complete code and output.

#### about the line arguments

Consider this program `p` at start

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc < 2)
   {
       printf("\tNo arguments provided!\n");
       return -1;
   }
   printf(
       "    %d arguments on the command line\n\n", argc - 1);
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
       printf("    #%d    \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Presented with these arguments

```
        p 1 2 3 4 5 5
```

This is the output:

```
    6 arguments on the command line

    #1    "1"
    #2    "2"
    #3    "3"
    #4    "4"
    #5    "5"
    #6    "5"
```

The operating system is providing the array. There is no need to convert this to another array of `int` just to insert into the linked list. We can just use these values and in this order.

#### A linked list

This is what you call a linked list:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int          number;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

**But it is not**. Failure on seeing this will make your life really harder around daa structures. Do you have a ext-book on that?

**A linked list is a --- possibly empty --- collection of nodes**. Each node constains or points to some data.

**A node is not a list. A list is not a node.**

#### Rewriting: a Node

This is a node:

```
typedef struct s_n
{
    int         number;
    struct s_n* next;
} Node;
```

Note that having pointers to only one direction is much more complicated than having `next` and `prev` pointers. Single linked lists are harder than double linked lists to manage.

Why? Navigation. For example when you need to delete a node --- and you will --- and have only `next` pointers you must remember that, unless you are deleting the first element, some previous node points to the one you are deleting, but **you do not have its address**...

Supose list is `{ v, x, y }`. When deleting `x` if you had `prev` pointer in `Node` then `x->prev` points to `v` and `v->next` points to `x`. And `x->next` points to `y`.

In order to delete `x` you must point `v` to `y` and `y` pointing back to `v` before deleting `x`. And it is easy:
`x->prev->next = y` and `y->prev = v`. Then `x` can be deleted.

If you have only `next` pointers you need to save state in the code for `delete`. See the example below.

#### And a list

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    head;
    Node*    tail;
} List;
```

Now we have a list AND a node. Note the convention of reserving the first letter in uppercase for names created in the program.

As you see the list has 2 pointers, because we want to keep the values in the order of insertion and it would not be efficient to traverse the list every time just to get the address of the last node.
And, as it is handy to know how many nodes are in the list at any time, we also have `size`. I believe that is easy to know how it is `unsigned` value.

You can for sure go without `size` but it is way simpler to always know the number of items in the if it is always in the list.

#### Some planning

Just before programming anything, let us see the operations we will need and how the program will work.

The operations:

- delete
- add
- find

At program start the list will be created with the values supplied in the command line. If there were none the list will be created empty, since all operations are still possible on an empty list

#### Some functions

In the style of RAII in `C++` at first we have

```
List* create();
List* destroy(List* toGo);
```

Using this way makes life easier: one can create `List` in a single line and to destroy a `List` we can at the same time guarantee that the list pointer is invalidated: no chance of dangling pointers.

Note that we do no have yet a single line of code. Just looking around the data.

#### More functions

If we want to destroy a list it is clear that we will need to delete all nodes before deleting the list in itself, or else we will leak memory.
As we are testing, it is clear that we will need an option to print the list contents also. So we add these functions as a minimum

```
int   add(int data, List* list);
Node* delete(int one, List* list);
int   display(List* list, const char* title);
int   find(int one, List* list);
```

Since we have some definitions and the original program that echoes the line arguments we can write a second program

#### A second program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_n
{
    int         number;
    struct s_n* next;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    head;
    Node*    tail;
} List;

List* create();
List* destroy(List* toGo);
int add(int data, List* list);
int delete(int one, List* list);
int display(List* list, const char* title);
int find(int one, List* list);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\tNo arguments provided!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "    %d arguments on the command line\n\n",
        argc - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        printf("    #%d    \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

List* create() { return NULL; }
List* destroy(List* toGo) { return NULL; }

int add(int data, List* list) { return 0; }
int delete(int one, List* list);
int display(List* list, const char* title) { return 0; }
int find(int one, List* list) { return 0; }
```

And we can even run it...

#### `create` and `destroy` list

To create a list is just a matter of allocating memory for it and marking it as empty

```
List* create()
{
    List* one = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->size = 0;
    one->head = NULL;
    one->tail = NULL;
    return one;
}
```

To delete a list is also basic: we know we have `size` nodes and we know how to delete each one, since we have a function for that, so...

```
List* destroy(List* gone)
{
    if (gone == NULL) return NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gone->size; i += 1)
    {
        Node* p = gone->head->next;
        free(gone->head);
        gone->head = p;
    }
    free(gone);
    return NULL;
};
```

This is ok since nodes here do not allocate memory.

#### A third `program`

Now we can run this version of main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    List* my_list = create();
    my_list       = destroy(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `destroy()` always returns `NULL` and it may seem silly. But the target is to be able to invalidate the `List` pointer in the same line that the list is destroyed, and in the code that calls `destroy()`:

```
    my_list       = destroy(my_list);
```

This leaves no chance for a dangling invalid pointer to remain lost in the calling code...

And it runs ok! It does little but it is good for moral support

#### inserting data: `add()`

```
int add(int data, List* list)
{  // insert at last element
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->number = data;  // data copied to node
    p->next = NULL;  // inserted at tail
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        list->head = list->tail = p;
        list->size              = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    list->tail->next = p;
    list->tail       = p;
    list->size += 1;  // count it in
    return 0;
}
```

A bit more than 10 lines. Note that we use the `tail` pointer to insert at the end and preserve the insertion order of the nodes. Anyway to insert at the beginning or `head` is identical, just using the `head` pointer and make your `node->next` point to `head` first before reassigning `head`.

#### To test this we need `display()`

It is obvious that we can call `display()` on an empty list or on a list with dozens of items. Or even with an invalid pointer, so let us do it.
The use of a title is very handy here, so no need to precede tests by the very very common `printf`s...

```
int display(List* list, const char* title)
{
    if (title != NULL) printf("%s", title);
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList does not exist\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nList size: %u\n  [ ", list->size);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->number);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
    return 0;
};
```

`display()` just follows the pointers. This list is really minimalist with a single number.

#### A 4th program now can even show some data

Consider this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\tNo arguments provided!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "    %d arguments on the command line\n", argc - 1);

    List* my_list = create();
    display(my_list, "list empty");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        add(atoi(argv[i]), my_list);
    display(my_list, "after insertions");
    my_list = destroy(my_list);
    display(my_list, "afer destroy()");
    return 0;
}
```

And the output for

```
    p 1 2 3 4 5
```

```
     5 arguments on the command line
list empty
List size: 0
  [ ]

after insertions
List size: 5
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

afer destroy()
List does not exist
```

Until now, no surprises: working at the first run as expected, since we wrote step by step around the data

#### `delete()` and `find()` simple implementations

These are similar to `display()` since it is the matter of navigate the whole list, but

- `delete()` return 0 when element is found and deleted
- `find()` returns the `Node` address when found, or `NULL`

This is a possible `delete()`:

```
int delete(int data, List* list)
{  // delete the 1st node that contains 'data'
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p    = list->head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->number == data)
        {  // this is the one
            if (p == list->head)
                list->head = p->next;
            else
            {
                prev->next = p->next;
                if (p == list->tail) list->tail = prev;
            }
            list->size -= 1;
            free(p);
            return 0;
        }
        prev = p;        // save state: no back pointer
        p    = p->next;  // go ahead
    }
    return -2;  // not found
};
```

about 15 lines due to the missing back pointers

And a possible `find()`:

```
Node* find(int data, List* list)
{  // return address of the first node with 'data'
    // or NULL if not found. Do not consider the
    // 'list` as sorted
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nfind(): List does not exist\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->number == data) return p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

### time for a 5th program

#### Inserting the command line arguments, if any

Now it is a good time to bring back the very first program and insert the arguments that came on the command line.

It can not be hard since we already have `add()`. The arguments are strings, but it is good to know that we have also `atoi()` so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\tNo arguments provided!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "    %d arguments on the command line\n", argc - 1);

    List* my_list = create();
    display(my_list, "list empty");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        add(atoi(argv[i]), my_list);
    display(my_list, "after insertions");
    //
    delete (1, my_list);
    delete (3, my_list);
    delete (5, my_list);
    display(my_list, "after delete 1 3 & 5");
    //
    my_list = destroy(my_list);
    display(my_list, "afer destroy()");
    return 0;
}
```

3 calls to delete the first, last and a middle record were inserted for testing...

#### This line is the only new thing:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1) add(atoi(argv[i]), my_list);
```

Just calling `atoi()` before inserting the argument in the list.

We know that `add()` works, we know that `atoi()` works, and the rest we already tested, so it is just a matter of copy and paste stuff.

#### The output

```
    5 arguments on the command line
list empty
List size: 0
  [ ]

after insertions
List size: 5
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

after delete 1 3 & 5
List size: 2
  [ 2 4 ]

afer destroy()
List does not exist
```

### The complete example up to now

#### `C` code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_n
{
    int         number;
    struct s_n* next;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Node*    head;
    Node*    tail;
} List;

List* create();
List* destroy(List* toGo);
int   add(int data, List* list);
int   delete(int one, List* list);
int   display(List* list, const char* title);
Node* find(int one, List* list);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\tNo arguments provided!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "    %d arguments on the command line\n", argc - 1);

    List* my_list = create();
    display(my_list, "list empty");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        add(atoi(argv[i]), my_list);
    display(my_list, "after insertions");
    //
    delete (1, my_list);
    delete (3, my_list);
    delete (5, my_list);
    display(my_list, "after delete 1 3 & 5");
    //
    my_list = destroy(my_list);
    display(my_list, "afer destroy()");
    return 0;
}

List* create()
{
    List* one = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->size = 0;
    one->head = NULL;
    one->tail = NULL;
    return one;
}

List* destroy(List* gone)
{
    if (gone == NULL) return NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gone->size; i += 1)
    {
        Node* p = gone->head->next;
        free(gone->head);
        gone->head = p;
    }
    free(gone);
    return NULL;
};

int add(int data, List* list)
{  // insert at last element
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p   = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->number = data;  // data copied to node
    p->next   = NULL;  // inserted at tail
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        list->head = list->tail = p;
        list->size              = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    list->tail->next = p;
    list->tail       = p;
    list->size += 1;  // count it in
    return 0;
}

int delete(int data, List* list)
{  // delete the 1st node that contains 'data'
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    Node* p    = list->head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->number == data)
        {  // this is the one
            if (p == list->head)
                list->head = p->next;
            else
            {
                prev->next = p->next;
                if (p == list->tail) list->tail = prev;
            }
            list->size -= 1;
            free(p);
            return 0;
        }
        prev = p;        // save state: no back pointer
        p    = p->next;  // go ahead
    }
    return -2;  // not found
};

int display(List* list, const char* title)
{
    if (title != NULL) printf("%s", title);
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList does not exist\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nList size: %u\n  [ ", list->size);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->number);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
    return 0;
};

Node* find(int data, List* list)
{  // return address of the first node with 'data'
    // or NULL if not found. Do not consider the
    // 'list` as sorted
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nfind(): List does not exist\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->number == data) return p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

I only wanted to show a way of write such things.

There are tests missing for `find()` but it is the same as `delete()`. Please let me know if it helps and if there are something I could add.

Comment: he's solving problems from the CS50 course offered by harvard online... this belongs not on stackoverflow the way its been asked, and you've given him too much answers for the course though you made an excellent post.  I dont agree with everything you've said about stable lists and such, but your overall content is great and your effort is well spent +1  In a list there is nothing wrong with front insertion of back insertion.  In an array I'd agree with your front insertion postulate.

Comment: might as well make `add` void if you always return 0

Comment: he is at the point in the course where they are making a single-linked list, hence the lack of previous. What he calls a list is technically a defined singly linked list if he uses a pointer to a node to call the head of his list. it's not c++ he doesnt HAVE to have a length and head and a tail (though those are great things that are worth having) and your points demonstrating their use are excellent

Comment: not sure why you have destroy return anything. unless you want `x = destroy(x)` which is just horrible syntax.  I'd just make it take a pointer to pointer and internally set it to NULL if you want to do that so badly.

Comment: Thanks,  @UpAndAdam, about these aspects [1] I agree it is not an error back insertion or even front insertion in a list. What I said is that in general we want the list stable, preserving the insertion order. One problem is for exemple to copy a list into another one. If using the same functions the copy will reverse the items, so an invariant is lost if using just `add()`

Comment: [2] I just did not write all tests and functions. `add` should return a negative value for errors. Even on a trivial case like this: at least the pointer to `List` should be tested for `NULL`

Comment: [3] I use this _horrible_ syntax `x = destroy(x)` as a clear way to invalidate the pointer in the calling code in the same line. I prefer it many times over a `List**` thing

Comment: fair enough, like I said great job with this. you really put time into this post and laid it out well and explained things in a great manner. Agree with you in general on lists, you want to be able to copy a list normally. and i'd never use an `add` method i'd have `push_front`,`push_back` and `insert` ( which the other two would use via inlining).

Comment: fair enough on #3 to each their own.  I just shudder when I see lines like that.  :-) I shouldn't have said horrible, I should have said horrible IMHO.

Comment: [4] about a _single linked list_  I wanted to make clear that the one with a single pointer is much more hard to program, but it seems that that instructors and students sees the presence of both pointers as more complex. It is not.

Comment: No disagreement on #4, thats just all they are doing at this point in the learning. This is their very first one so they are learning a singly linked list so they can contrast with double on the next assignment

Comment: oh funny times. SO does not like chatting on comments! I received a warning. Cheers @UpAndAdam. Thank you for your time here! HIH the OP

Comment: @UpAndAdam the students have a hard time coding `delete()` and navigating on single linked list, in their first assigment. Only to discover shortly after that double linked lists are way simpler. Not fair.

Comment: gotta learn to crawl before you learn to walk. plus it works on improving their thinking skills and experience with pointers.  you'd be surprised at the number of folks who do it different ( front insertion, back insertion by insertion stupidly, back insertion with a tail pointer)

Comment: nothing stops them from doing double linked... and one or two of them come up with it... but its not "suggested to them" yet.

Comment: @UpAndAdam ;) this is more a case of needing to walk before crawl: when they see that is much easier to have pointers to both directions the students may wonder why to teach single linked lists first. I added  sample code for `delete` and `find`to the answer.

Comment: Wow. I really can't thank you enough for the effort you put into this. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome you are. This one of yours is a good question and having at least one possible solution here, in a searchable way, can help others. Please test question and method and reply if needed!

Comment: I have one question about how the head changes with the changing of the tail. Using debugging, I found that right after this line of code sets off (list->tail->next = p;) head instantly gains that value as well. Why is this the case?

Comment: Also, I wonder if there is an efficient way for the user themselves to choose what they want to do. Lets say I asked "Write 'a' if you want to add, 'd' for delete, 'f' for find, and 's' for show/display".  Lets say they choose ‘a’. Then i would ask them to write what they would want to add. I got that data before using the get_string function from cs50, but I’m wondering if there’s anyother way to do it?

Comment: And then I went through this process of turning the string into the several ints the user provided. But I hit a error when I tried to return this array of integers, and I thought it was because c didn’t allow that. So I made it a pointer, but then it only pointed to the first item in that array. So i’m wondering if theres an efficent way to get ints from the user thats not from the command line, while also being able to use all of those ints.

Comment: @Harr you do no need this array. System already gave you one to use: `argv[]`. Did you noticed where I used the arguments? just at the precise moment of inserting them into he list. You just need one `int` at a time. The `argv[]`array is yours to keep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255061/discussion-between-harr-and-arfneto).